# PySpark: Pandas UDF for scipy statistical transformations

Tags: pyspark, pandas-udf

I'm trying to create a column of standardized (z-score) of a column x on a Spark dataframe, but am missing something because none of it is working.

Here's my example:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from scipy.stats import zscore

@pandas_udf('float')
def zscore_udf(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return zscore(x)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

columns = ["id","x"]
data = [("a", 81.0),
    ("b", 36.2),
    ("c", 12.0),
    ("d", 81.0),
    ("e", 36.3),
    ("f", 12.0),
    ("g", 111.7)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)

df.show()

df = df.withColumn('y', zscore_udf(df.x))

df.show()
```

Which results in obviously wrong calculations:

```
+---+-----+----+
| id|    x|   y|
+---+-----+----+
|  a| 81.0|null|
|  b| 36.2| 1.0|
|  c| 12.0|-1.0|
|  d| 81.0| 1.0|
|  e| 36.3|-1.0|
|  f| 12.0|-1.0|
|  g|111.7| 1.0|
+---+-----+----+
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**How to fix:**
instead of using a UDF calculate the `stddev_pop` and the `avg` of the dataframe and calculate z-score manually.
I suggest using "window function" over the entire dataframe for the first step and then a simple arithmetic to get the z-score.
see suggested code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, col, stddev_pop
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df \
.select(
    "*",
    avg("x").over(Window.partitionBy()).alias("avg_x"),
    stddev_pop("x").over(Window.partitionBy()).alias("stddev_x"),
) \
.withColumn("manual_z_score", (col("x") - col("avg_x")) / col("stddev_x"))
```

**Why the UDF didn't work?**
Spark is used for distributed computation. When you perform operations on a DataFrame Spark distributes the workload into partitions on the executors/workers available.

`pandas_udf` is not different. When running a UDF from the type pd.Series -> pd.Series some rows are sent to partition X and some to partition Y, then when `zscore` is run it calculates the mean and std of the data in the partition and writes the zscore based on that data only.

I'll use `spark_partition_id` to "prove" this.
rows a,b,c were mapped in partition 0 while d,e,f,g in partition 1. I've calculated manually the mean/stddev_pop of both the entire set and the partitioned data and then calculated the z-score. the UDF z-score was equal to the z-score of the partition.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, spark_partition_id, avg, stddev, col, stddev_pop
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df \
.select(
    "*",
    zscore_udf(df.x).alias("z_score"),
    spark_partition_id().alias("partition"),
    avg("x").over(Window.partitionBy(spark_partition_id())).alias("avg_partition_x"),
    stddev_pop("x").over(Window.partitionBy(spark_partition_id())).alias("stddev_partition_x"),
) \
.withColumn("partition_z_score", (col("x") - col("avg_partition_x")) / col("stddev_partition_x"))

df2.show()

+---+-----+-----------+---------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
| id|    x|    z_score|partition|  avg_partition_x|stddev_partition_x|   partition_z_score|
+---+-----+-----------+---------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
|  a| 81.0|   1.327058|        0|43.06666666666666|28.584533502500186|  1.3270579815484989|
|  b| 36.2|-0.24022315|        0|43.06666666666666|28.584533502500186|-0.24022314955974558|
|  c| 12.0| -1.0868348|        0|43.06666666666666|28.584533502500186| -1.0868348319887526|
|  d| 81.0|  0.5366879|        1|            60.25|38.663063768925504|  0.5366879387524718|
|  e| 36.3|-0.61945426|        1|            60.25|38.663063768925504| -0.6194542714757446|
|  f| 12.0| -1.2479612|        1|            60.25|38.663063768925504|  -1.247961110593097|
|  g|111.7|  1.3307275|        1|            60.25|38.663063768925504|  1.3307274433163698|
+---+-----+-----------+---------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

I also added df.repartition(8) prior to the calculation and managed to get similar results as in the original question.
partitions with 0 stddev --> null z score, partition with 2 rows --> (-1, 1) z scores.

```
+---+-----+-------+---------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| id|    x|z_score|partition|avg_partition_x|stddev_partition_x|partition_z_score|
+---+-----+-------+---------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
|  a| 81.0|   null|        0|           81.0|               0.0|             null|
|  d| 81.0|   null|        0|           81.0|               0.0|             null|
|  f| 12.0|   null|        1|           12.0|               0.0|             null|
|  b| 36.2|   -1.0|        6|          73.95|             37.75|             -1.0|
|  g|111.7|    1.0|        6|          73.95|             37.75|              1.0|
|  c| 12.0|   -1.0|        7|          24.15|12.149999999999999|             -1.0|
|  e| 36.3|    1.0|        7|          24.15|12.149999999999999|              1.0|
+---+-----+-------+---------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I appreciate the fuller explanation with code.